# Eclipse Kepler crashes on Ubuntu 14.04 when using WindowBuilder

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse, jdk

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04` and with a lot of problems I have to face daily with this OS, there is another recent one.

**Problem: Whenever I try to use Eclipse's WindowBuilder to design SWING GUIs, after a few clicks/tasks on window canvas, Eclipse suddenly hangs up, I have to force quit Eclipse. I restart eclipse and all my previous progress is lost (obviously).**

Setup:

- Java JDK = JavaSE7 x64 - Oracle Java (not Open JDK - well both JDKs cause
  same problem)
- Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 (JEE Edition) x64
- Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop (installed with LiveUSB)
- HP dv6 - OS installed on SSD

Kindly help me out here. I was creating a GUI based project on windows, and Eclipse+Windowbuilder works like a charm there. *[I don't want to go back to Windows.. screams....]*

For any kind of logs required, please do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the oracle java8 (or version.x) installer.  It fixed all of my problems and was easy.
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

Answer (score -1):

This is a general problem with Kepler on 14.04. If you look at crash reports, it is open-jdk that is actually crashes. I experience the same problem with PDT.

## **UPDATE:**

Now i actually **found a workaround** (not a solution):

To get your Eclipse running stable on Ubuntu 14.04 you will have to use **32-Bit** Version of **JRE**! *(Oracle or OpenJDK whatever you prefer)*

## **WHAT TO DO**

install x86 openjdk

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk:i386
```

then switch between jre you currently have *(choose java-7-openjdk-i386)*

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

obtain 32-Bit Version of Eclipse

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

### Endnote

Currently im running Eclipse Luna (with a lot of plugins!) on Ubuntu 14.04 with openjdk7-i386 and since 1 Week i had not a single Crash! Actually i am SAD because Eclipse cannot use all 32 GB of my RAM >:( It means for me if Oracle maintains java they messed up alot.